# WebStorm, Meteor and phone tests

Tags: testing, meteor, webstorm

I am developing a web application with Meteor and WebStorm as IDE.
This application can be called from a PC, a tablet or a phone, which does not pose a problem of execution since it is called in the browser.
On the other hand problems appear, which are due to the size of the screen and the positioning portrait or landscape.
To test, a solution is to deploy the app, open it in the phone browser and see what works or does not work. A bit heavy ...

Is there a method to test a web application on a device connected to the development PC, through WebStorm, can be with an added package, or with another tool

Any leads or ideas would be welcome.
Thank you for your answers
YC

Comment: Have you tried using Google Chrome's 'Developer Tools' ? It gives you the option to simulate a phone screen. For more info - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue, I used Ghostlabs (https://www.vanamco.com/ghostlab/), to test different screensizes simultaneously. You will need to have physical devices present and connected to your development machine.

Saucelabs(https://saucelabs.com/) in my opinion is an extension of Ghostlabs, with the advantages of using the cloud.

One other tool I would recommend is Browser stack (https://www.browserstack.com/) it gives similar benefits as Saucelabs.

These tools I find are very effective for cross browser testing too.